# Chrome.Runtime.SendMessage Not Workking

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a simple chrome extension that will read some data off the page, set a badge count on the extension icon and then display the data on my popup. However I'm struggling to get the data from my content script to my background js.

I have looked at many questions on SO about this and it seems to me like I'm doing everything right, but its still not working.

This is what I've done:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "icons": {
  "16": "images/icon-16.png",
  "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts.babel/chromereload.js",
      "scripts.babel/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost:9000/*"],
      "js":["scripts.babel/myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
   "permissions": [],
      "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": {
       "19": "images/icon-19.png",
       "38": "images/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "MiAssist",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

The content script:

**myscript.js**

```
"use strict";
var names = findNames();
sendNames(names);

function findNames()
{
  var names = [];
  //finds names..

  return names;
}

function sendNames(names)
{
  // Bind event:
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null, names, null,
    function(response) {
      // Do something
      ;
  });
}
```

**background.js**

```
'use strict';

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details => {
  console.log('previousVersion', details.previousVersion);
});

// Bind event:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(names, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("background.js");
    if(names.length > 0)
    {
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: names.length});
    }
});
```

All of this doesn't work. The onMessage anonymous function is never reached.

Could somebody please help me with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try without the first null in sendMessage

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, however that didn't work :(

Comment: Debug it by setting breakpoints inside content script and the background script.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `null` for optional arguments. If you need a message and callback only - just pass only two this args.

I tried you code with my remark and it works:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(names, 
  function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  }
);
```